# JUnit 5 tests are not firing and tests aren't showing in test runner

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, junit5

I am having trouble getting JUnit 5 tests to run on VSCODE.  I believe my environment is set up properly.  A clone of *junit5-samples | junit5-jupiter-starter-maven* builds and runs as expected. My project does not.

My project builds under maven but runs no tests.  So this is probably a Maven or project configuration issue and not related to VSCODE.

I have tinkered with various ideas for a couple of hours to no avail.  Something is different, probably a mistake and maybe additional pairs of eyes can find it.  Any help you might provide will be greatly appreciated.

**Here is some project information**

'mvn clean package' runs without error, but no tests run. CodeLens is also not working.

**Run Test|Debug Test** is missing.  No tests show up in test runner.
[image]

Here is my POM file with a few redactions:

```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
  <artifactId>redacted</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.1</version>
  <name>redacted</name>

  <properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit.jupiter.version>
  </properties>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests> -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin> -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
              <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                  <wsdl>${basedir}/WSDL/redacted.wsdl</wsdl>
                </wsdlOption>
              </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the output from the mvn command:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.redacted:redactedClient >-------------------------
[INFO] Building redactedClient 0.1.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\repos\redacted\redactedClient\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.6:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\repos\redacted\redactedClient\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to D:\repos\redacted\redactedClient\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\repos\redacted\redactedClient\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\repos\redacted\redactedClient\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ redactedClient ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.444 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-26T09:55:55-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should add `junit-jupiter-engine` as a dependency instead of `junit-jupiter`. Surefire 2.22.X will be triggered by that. In surefire 3.X junit-jupier-api is working

Comment: I would why your test method `GetModList()` returns something usually a test method has `void` ... you can remove the `public` from your test methods as well from the test class itself.

Comment: I will try both the above.  I have determined that the target folder does not contain the class AppTest.class file.  So maybe the AppTest.java is not being selected to compile?

Comment: @ khmarbaise No joy switching to void and dropping public.  For some reason Maven is not compiling AppTest.java .  A file name search in the target folder shows no reference to "AppTest"

Comment: Surefire is running.  It's just not finding any tests.  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ IDDClient ---
[INFO] No tests to run.  At this point I think there are no tests to run because the test source code is not being compiled.

Comment: Please make a project on GitHub and post  the link..so I can take a look at it...

Comment: I can't place this project on GitHub, while it is intended to be open source, our legal department is still doing paperwork.  I can post any output listings or logs.

Comment: make an example project which looks a like that...

Comment: I'll copy the folder whack out or stub code most of the code, create dummy WSDLs and see about putting it up.  In the meantime if anyone can send ideas regarding why the build process might be skipping the test java files.  I suspect that's what is happening.

Comment: BTW: In which location do you have put your test class: `src/test/java/Package/AppTest.java` ?

Comment: I do.  However it's working.  I think I made two changes at the same time.  One fixed the issue and the other broke it with the same symptoms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212572/discussion-between-bigtfromaz-and-khmarbaise).

Comment: @khmarbaise please post your second comment regarding void and public a the proposed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test method should have the return type `void` whereas your test method `GetModList()` has `Boolean`.

In JUnit Jupiter you can remove public from the test class also from all test methods.

Comment: A quick note: this took a while for me to sort out because this POM entry in <build> 
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
also causes the same symptoms.  I had added it between posting the question and trying @khmarbaise's initial suggestions.  The folder there does exist so I am not sure why it would cause a problem. Doing the same for source code works just fine.

 <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

Comment: You should remove `<sourceDirectory>..</sourceDirectory>` and `<testSourceDirectory>..</testSourceDirectory>` configuration cause it violates convention over configuration paradigm..

Comment: Directory overrides don't well .  Unfortunately this is being driven by the need to add JUnit to a number of projects that currently use command line tests.  The projects are using /src/com/domain/project/type/subtypes, not standard.  what I have been testing is can we just add tests?, How difficult will it be to refactor.  So far the answer is not good.  I spent the entire weekend focusing on the tooling and in a word, my report to management will be "fragile".